# Notifying Password Change

Tags: ibm-information-server

- When you change the password for the xmeta user (owner of the metadata repository) you can run AppServerAdmin script with -db option to provide the new password into “the system”.
- Is there an equivalent script for notifying a password change for user xmetasr (owner of the staging area for the metadata repository)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a patch, included in Fix Pack 1, that enables a new option (-dbs) that allows you to set the xmetasr user's password.